# "The" is not in sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence

Can I write sentence "what is difference" instead of "what is the difference"? 
I have to know because I have purchased domain whatisdifference.com

Comment: I would interpret the question "What is difference?" as asking what the meaning of the word _difference_ is. If the question is supposed to mean "What difference does [something] make?" or "How do thing X and thing Y differ?" I think the most natural-sounding wording in informal English might be "What's the difference?"

Comment: I would interpret "What is difference?" as a query from [Chekov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavel_Chekov) or some other individual with less than average fluency in English as a second language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What is difference?* asks what the nature of dissimilarity is.

*What is **the** difference?* asks about a particular distinction between two things.

Comment: Would you say there is no chance at all that the former will be interpreted to mean the latter?

Comment: @Rathony Quite possibly. But it wouldn't make it a correct interpretation. If the speaker was someone with a heavy non-English accent, I would probably assume they meant the latter. However if it were said by an Anglophonic person giving an academic lecture, I would presume there to be a good reason why the article had not been included.

Comment: @Rathony There is a nonzero probability that any two similar statements will be mistakenly interpreted by someone as meaning the same thing. But if a native English speaker unfamiliar with Thai cuisine were asked whether he preferred red curry or green curry, it is highly unlikely he would ask about the difference and omit the article. On the other hand, few will think the distinction worth worrying about in a domain name.

Comment: @Rathony There is a chance, but omitting the "the" is a sign of poor English.

Comment: dissimilarity means distinction between two things so it is acceptable to write what is difference if **The** is not present is sentence?

Comment: The idiomatic way to ask about a distinction between two things is to use the definite article: *What is **the** difference?*